# Creating a collection of multiple same-depth values in a nested hashmap

Tags: dictionary, clojure, hashmap, destructuring

Here is a hypothetical hashmap named args:

```clj
{:body {:milestones [{:status 1 :otherValues x} 
                     {:status 2 :otherValues z} 
                     {:status 1 :otherValues y]}}
```

My goal is to have a collection of the values for each :status key. They are all at the same depth being the child of :milestones.

I'm getting close. I know how to retrieve the value of the first status by doing this:

```clj
(let [{[{:keys [status]} x] :milestones} :body} args]
  (println status))
```

The very far end goal is to find out which maps contain a :status with a value of 1 and create a new collection with each individual map.

The literal application of this is connecting to TeamworkPM and syncing up milestones with a status of "late" or "incomplete" with Google Calenders.

Desired output would be {1, 2, 1} in this scenario. The end goal is to have

```clj
 {{:status 1 :otherValues x} 
  {:status 1 :otherValues Y}}
```

Comment: can you give us an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I couldn't find out how to destructure the vector of map into a variable directly,
instead you can first get the child of `:milestones`, and then use basic `map` or `filter`.

Note that you can get the value of map by applying it as function. (e.g. if `m` is `{:key1 "val1"}`, `(m :key1)` would be `"val1"`)

```
(def args {:body {:milestones [{:status 1 :otherValues 'x}
                               {:status 2 :otherValues 'z}
                               {:status 1 :otherValues 'y}]}})

(let [{{x :milestones} :body} args,
        y (map #(% :status) x),
        z (filter #(= (% :status) 1) x)
      ]
      (println x) ; [{:status 1, :otherValues x} {:status 2, :otherValues z} {:status 1, :otherValues y}]
      (println y) ; (1 2 1)
      (println z) ; ({:status 1, :otherValues x} {:status 1, :otherValues y})
  )
```

Comment: Wow, this is incredible. My heart goes out to you for [a (answering question) b (displaying it so nicely) c (displaying 3 different outputs)].

Comment: `#(% :status)` is just a weird way to write `:status` (when applied to a map arg, at least).